# Abelian groups in Elliptic curves

Tags: elliptic-curves, finite-field, group-theory

Do every elliptic curve defined over a prime field forms an abelian group?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about general mathematics.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, every elliptic curve (that is, smooth projective curve of genus one over a field) admits a *natural* group structure on its set of points.

<sub><sup>(Note: [Any nonempty set can be equipped with an abelian group structure](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/105440/426401), but you are probably only interested in the "nice" group structure on elliptic curves given by rational maps.)</sup></sub>

This is a consequence to the Riemann-Roch theorem, which implies that the canonical map $E\to \mathrm{Pic}^0(E)$ is a bijection, and the latter is an abelian group by construction.